# Mutate component to render children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I'm trying to create a HOC which adds a tooltip (later can be more reusable). I've come up with a few working solutions using other methods, but I'd like to make it as simple as possible to use.

Basically, I want to know if there is anyway to force my `<Div />` component to render its children without adding `{props.children}` to the `<Div />`. If that's possible somehow, then I could really make this better in the future.

```
import { nest } from 'recompose';

const Tooltip = () => <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, height: '20px', width: '20px', backgroundColor: 'red' }} />;

const Div = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
        height: '400px',
      }}
    >
      <h1>content here</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

const DivWithTooltip = nest(Div, Tooltip);
```

Comment: Why do you not want to write `{props.children}`? You want to render the children, you have to explicit write it.

Comment: @Isaddo Well, I'd like to create some kind of helper which just adds some hover effect to the component such as adding a tooltip. I can do it cleanly by wrapping the component in a `<Hover>` component but I'm just trying to see if it's possible using a clean HOC. That way I can just say `Component = withHover(Component, TooltipComponent)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? You can use `span` wrapper instead of `div` to minimize possible styling problems, generally there is no problem. Use wrapper or `props.children`, you have to choose one.

```js
const withToolTip = ToolTip => Component => props => (
  <div className="tooltip">
    <Component {...props} />
    <ToolTip {...props} />
  </div>
)

const Div = props => (
  <div>Hover over me</div>
)
const Tip = props => (
  <div className="tooltiptext">tip</div>
)
const DivWithTooltip = withToolTip(Tip)(Div)

ReactDOM.render(
  <DivWithTooltip />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```css
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like this indeed, but wasn't sure if having the extra `div` as a wrapper would cause any issues with the styling